# Module name type, or autocompletion

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

In Typescript, I can write

```js
let mod = await import("redis");
```

and get auto-completion for all modules when entering a value for the import. Is this a special case, or can I get the same behavior using a type on a function that I define, like

```js
let my_import = (module: ???) => import(module)
```

or is there another way to get module name auto-completion?

Comment: @sheng wait, did I not try it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not autocompletion-help service.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel You don't understand my question. I'm asking if Typescript has a feature which allows you to enter a module name, and get a list of module names in the auto completion feature of the editor, like there are for other types, not "fill in the blank"

Comment: I do understand your question. Syntax in the first example is used all over so editors/code completion plugins/etc support it. Second one is uncommon at best.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel What? The second example isn't "uncommon", it's invalid. It's asking if there is a type that represents project modules, or some other way to create a function that can have similar auto completion as import(). (which, there likely isn't due to the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a special case. `import()` is not a function call, and `import` is not a function - it is specific syntax.

Comment: i edited my question, I don't particularly care if this is a special case, I am trying to figure out module auto completion.

Comment: @kalkronline I'm pretty sure you can't get module name autocompletion.